# Finding which of two points is to the right

Tags: algorithm, vector, camera, three.js

Suppose I have two vector3s, one for camera position, the other for the target position. I also have two vectors V1, V2 from each side of the camera. I don't know which one of them is on the right, but one of them is on the right for certain.

It looks like this from above:

[image]

How can I know if V1 is on the right or on the left?

I have a built in function to move the camera to the right, so I thought to do that and check distances and return it to its original position, but that's an ugly solution.

I also thought to use the dot product between the {target - camera} and {V1 - camera} vectors, and if it's positive, then it's on the right, and if negative on the left, but it appears that it doesn't work like that because for example:

`{0,1,0}.{1,1,0} = {0,1,0}.{-1,1,0} = 1`

Any other ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Sorry for a very half-baked comment but I think `atan2` will help.

Comment: Arctan 2? What is the 2? What it receives? I'm not sure if three.js has that. @AhmedFasih

Comment: To define term "right" in 3d space, it is not enough to get one vector (camera-target), you need one more selected direction - for example, direction of axis of rotation `to move the camera to the right`.

Comment: What if all 4 positions in the picture have the same height? That's like looking at 2D space, does it help? @Mbo

Comment: And we know the we look at this scene from the top? If so, this fact gives us needed additional direction.

Comment: We look from the camera,the two vectors and target will be in front of the camera. So what is the correct calculation? @Mbo

Comment: See [this math answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214187/point-on-the-left-or-right-side-of-a-plane-in-3d-space). The three points in the plane you could use are `camera`, `target`, and (for instance) `camera + (0, 0, 1)`, since you seem to be interested in a plane perpendicular to the xy-plane.

Comment: What?! How a determinant is related to angles? @VincentvanderWeele

Comment: I have no idea :)

Comment: Determinant is vector product that defines how is some vector triplet oriented.

Comment: @MBo where did you see this definition? I know that a determinant in R^2 represent an area so in R^3 it should represent a volume, that's quite different than orientation.

Comment: Correct name - mixed product . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product Positive volume - 'right-hand' orientation, negative - 'left-hand'.

Comment: Sorry for my half-baked suggestions, but, especially if you are limited to the 2D case, [`Math.atan2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, the answer is to take the normal of the plane spanned by `{cam, target, cam + up}` and do dot product with `v1`.

i.e: `{{cam + up} - {cam} x {target - cam}} . {v1 - cam}`

Which is the same as `det({cam + up} - {cam} | {target - cam} | {v1 - cam})` since all three subtractions are linearly independent.